# SVN can't connect to localhost: target machine actively refused it

Tags: svn

I installed Tortoisesvn and SVN. I then successfully did the following

`svnadmin create "c:svnrepository"` and 
edited `conf\svnserve.conf` by removing the pound character from:

```
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

added users to `conf/passwd`

typed `sc create svnserver ...`

when I run `net start svnserver`, but it said `system error 87 has occurred. the parameter is incorrect`

I then typed

```
set SVN_EDITOR=c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe
svn mkdir svn://localhost/myproj
```

I saw some previous suggestions to this were to go to TortoiseSVN->Settings. But I'm unable to right click on it to get there

I also tried `svnserve --daemon --root "path/to/my/repo` and `svnserve -d -r path/to/my/repo`, but they just freeze and do nothing

I also opened the Tortoise Repo Browser, but it gives the same error of Localhost connection being refused

can anyone help with this?

Comment: If you find it difficult to setup Subversion server manually, use [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/) - it installs in several clicks and gives you much more than a simple `svnserve`-based SVN installation.

Answer (score 0):

> svnadmin create "c:svnrepository"

The path in this command line is incorrect - it is missing the `\` character . It has to be `C:\svnrepository`. The command `svnadmin create "c:svnrepository"` creates a new repository in your current directory, not `C:\svnrepository`.

> I also tried svnserve --daemon --root "path/to/my/repo and svnserve -d
> -r path/to/my/repo, but they just freeze and do nothing

Most likely you either use invalid paths in your commands. Or the problem is with the path to your repository (see above).